# Display message on click of text box with two way data binding

Tags: angular

I have some simple code below using ngmodel. The welcome message should be displayed only on clicking the text box. This is regarding two way data binding. Which function should I use, ngmodelchange or keyup?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
app.component.ts 
@Component({
      selector: 'my-app', 
      template:`<div>
      <label>name:
        <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="(chooseone)" >
      </label>
      welcome {{hero.name}}
         </div>`,
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      values :string;
      hero = {
        name1: 'john',
        name: 'smith'
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably use:

```
<input  type="text" (click)="functionToCall()" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="(chooseone)">
```

If you want to display or change the value by typing in the input box the following should work for you.

```
<input  type="text" (input)="functionToCall()" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="(chooseone)">
```